# How can I get the apt-get source of a backports package on Debian?

Tags: debian, apt

My current sources.list:

```
## main & security repositories
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ lenny main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ lenny main
deb http://security.debian.org/ lenny/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ lenny/updates main

#deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ lenny contrib
#deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ lenny contrib
#deb http://security.debian.org/ lenny/updates contrib
#deb-src http://security.debian.org/ lenny/updates contrib

#deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ lenny non-free
#deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ lenny non-free
#deb http://security.debian.org/ lenny/updates non-free
#deb-src http://security.debian.org/ lenny/updates non-free

deb http://www.backports.org/debian lenny-backports main contrib non-free
```

Lenny stable has nginx 0.6.32. I have 0.7.6xish from lenny backports. I want to recompile the .deb with the `uwsgi` module. If I `apt-get source nginx` I am given the 0.6.32 files.

How can I modify my sources.list such that I get my lenny backports version? Or is that not possible? If so would I solely have to rely on sid? And if so, could someone tell me what exact lines I need to add for sid?

And if I do end up adding a deb-src line for sid, that's just temporary in order for me to run the `apt-get source nginx` command, because otherwise I'd be grabbing sid packages across the board?

Answer (score 3):

I copied `deb http://www.backports.org/debian lenny-backports main contrib non-free` and changed `deb` to `deb-src`.

Afterwards, I did a `apt-get update` and then `apt-get -t lenny-backports source nginx` and that did it.

Comment: That's the correct way ;-)